# uwp twoway binding not updating UI

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have the following XAML code, where I have a `TextBox` for user input (phone number) and `GridView` for user contacts.

```
<GridView x:Name="ContactsCollection" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DefaultGridView}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding UserContacts}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HorizontalGridViewDataTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DefaultGridViewItemContainer}">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <c:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <c:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectContactCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ContactsCollection}"/>
    </c:EventTriggerBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

And my `TextBox` that is binded to the `Recipient` in the ViewModel.

```
<TextBox x:Uid="Recipient" Text="{Binding Recipient, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="True" toolkitControls:TextBoxMask.Mask="7(999)999-99-99" toolkitControls:TextBoxMask.PlaceHolder="X" InputScope="NumericPin" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource UiControlHeaderDataTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

Here goes code from the ViewModel.

```
    public string Recipient
    {
        get { return _recipient; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _recipient)
            {
                _recipient = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Recipient));
                ContinueTransferCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when I click any contact from the GridView the following functions is called, that assign contact's phone number to the Recipient property.

```
    private void SelectContactCommandAction(object contact)
    {
        Contact c = contact as Contact;
        if (c.Phones?.Count > 0)
            Recipient = FormatDataHelper.FormatPhoneNumber(c.Phones.FirstOrDefault().Number);
    }
```

When I click any contact for the **FIRST** time, the Recipient property is updated, and the UI is updated too. But, if I select other contact, in the debug mode I can see, that Recipient property is updated and saved new value, but the UI (TextBox) is not updated at all. The only way it works, I have to delete any character from the TextBox and select a contact again, in that case UI value will be updated again.

Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: Implement INotifyOfPropertyChanged in your class, this will help

Comment: I can explain why, but now i'm on my phone :P

Comment: @sTrenat, thanks for your reply. I'm usign MVVM light toolkit that has ViewModelBase class, where INotifyPropertyChanged is already implemented and can be called using RaisePropertyChanged as it is written in my code.

Comment: Is your diagnostics output saying anything about databindig error?

Comment: Nope. Not even warning messages, Everything is correct.

Comment: If you you will set breakpoint on set, will it fire?

Comment: Yes, it fires on every change: from the UI and from the ViewModel. And after every change, value of the Recipient property is updated, but not the UI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153169/discussion-between-strenat-and-konstantin-chsherbakov).

Comment: Try x:Bind instead of Bindings and DependencyProperty instead of INotifyOfPropertyChanged.